# Editing URL character replacement

Tags: permalinks, slug, encoding, localization

Whereabouts can I edit which characters in permalinks are replaced? For example apostrophe's are replaced with nothing, and I would like to have them replaced with hyphens instead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter `'sanitize_title'` and use the second argument, the raw title. See my plugin [Germanix](https://github.com/toscho/Germanix-WordPress-Plugin/blob/master/germanix_url.php) for an example.